# jquery fullcalendar full translation

Tags: jquery, datetime, localization, fullcalendar, datetime-format

I'm correctly use JQuery FullCalendar in a project but I want to translate some data.

I read the documentation so I do this :

```
monthNames:['Janvier','Février','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin','Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Décembre'],
monthNamesShort:['janv.','févr.','mars','avr.','mai','juin','juil.','août','sept.','oct.','nov.','déc.'],
dayNames: ['Dimanche','Lundi','Mardi','Mercredi','Jeudi','Vendredi','Samedi'],
dayNamesShort: ['Dim', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Jeu', 'Ven', 'Sam'],
titleFormat: {
    month: 'MMMM yyyy',
    week: "d[ MMMM][ yyyy]{ - d MMMM yyyy}",
day: 'dddd d MMMM yyyy'
},
columnFormat: {
    month: 'ddd',
week: 'ddd d',
day: ''
},
axisFormat: 'H:mm', 
timeFormat: {
    '': 'H:mm', 
agenda: 'H:mm{ - H:mm}'
},
firstDay:1,
buttonText: {
    today: 'aujourd\'hui',
    day: 'jour',
    week:'semaine',
    month:'mois'
}, 
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
center: 'title',
right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
},
```

I use **eventClick** and **select** function to edit the calendar, it's work well.
But when I get the **event.start** or **event.end** inside one of this function the date is not translate... any idea to fix this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FullCalendar has built in [`.parseDate`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/parseDate/) and [`.formatDate`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/formatDate/) functions to assist with translating IETF dates.

First use `parseDate` to convert the date string into a JavaScript Date object.  After that, call `formatDate` with a format string and an options object.  This options object should contain the translated values for `monthNames`, `monthNamesShort`, `dayNames`, and `dayNamesShort`.

Here's an example function for formatting:

```
var formatDate = function(dateString) {
    var parsedDate = $.fullCalendar.parseDate(dateString);
    return $.fullCalendar.formatDate(parsedDate, 'dddd d MMMM yyyy',options);
}
```

If your formatting needs are more complex, you could also take a look at the [Date.js library](http://www.datejs.com/) which has good internationalization support.

Comment: Thanx it work well but now my date was save in french and fullCalendar do not understand french date, any idea to solve this point ? ^^

Comment: It sounds like you're persisting the value generated by formatting.  Try to make sure wherever you're saving that date, you're using the raw date string rather than the formatted string.  You could also look into the Date.js library I mentioned to reformat the date to IETF fromat if that's a problem.

Answer (score 2):

french speaking:

```
// time formats
titleFormat: {
    month: 'MMMM yyyy',
    // week: "MMM d[ yyyy]{ '&#8212;'[ MMM] d yyyy}",
    week:"'Semaine du' dd [yyyy] {'au' [MMM] dd MMM yyyy}",
    day: 'dddd dd MMM yyyy'
},
columnFormat: {
    month: 'ddd',
    week: 'ddd dd/M',
    day: 'dddd dd/M' 
},
timeFormat: { // for event elements
    '': 'HH:mm'
},
```

Answer (score 2):

week:`"'Semaine du' dd  [MMM] [yyyy] {'au' dd MMM yyyy}",`